# Am I allowed to convert vector fields to spherical coordinates to make the easier?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

For example, how would I find div F if

$$F = \left\langle 
\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}, 
\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}},\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}
\right\rangle $$

Could I just use spherical coordinates to make it more simple?

Comment: Yes, of course! It is a good idea indeed! 
But you need to use the spherical versions of the differential operators, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Spherical_coordinates.

What do you want to compute, the gradient, i.e. $\nabla F$, or the divergence $\mathrm{div}( F )$?

Comment: Sorry, instead of dif F I meant div F. I want to find the divergence